# Cocoapods - Hide implementation?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a iOS library that I created. Quite now I shipped this lib in a `.framework` file with only some **.h** files.
Now I would like to use Cocoapods instead of the framework.

Is it possible to hide the **.m** files and expose only some header files (like with the framework)?

According to this question I don't understand the relation between the podspec settings `source_files` and `public_header_files`.

I assumed that `public_header_files` would be my needed option, but I don't understand what this property is doing.

**Edit:**
I think I misunderstood the design of Cocoapods. `public_header_files` seems to make sense when using the `use_framework!` setting. 
Maybe I'm trying Carthage instead.

Comment: how to hide .m files, any idea ?

Comment: @Vashum Never figured out if this is possible. I think it is not possible, also not with Carthage. With Carthage you can link to releases (e.g. .framework files), but only for github. For Cocoapods: Maybe it's possible to define only a .framework file as the source, but I never tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Objective-C static framework, it is possible, you can try [cocoapods-packager](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager).
For Swift framework, so far it is impossible to use cocoapods-packager because of no volunteers. You can find the detailed information [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager/issues/115):

But there is another way to [Hide implementation of Swift framework when distributing it](https://dahuayuan.wordpress.com/2017/10/12/hide-implementation-of-swift-framework-when-distri/)

Comment: It should be noted that resource files, objc header files, and public swift files will not be obfuscated when building a framework and distributing it via cocoapods.